# Game help in C, functions that connects buy and sell (with price)

Tags: c, menu

Hello is there a way to connect two functions together, I'm creating menu game that accepts input from the user. Price selling and buying functions to be connected. so when a user wants to buy, sell the data is entered to the inventory of the player .

```
int getBuy (int nBuy) //Buy only
{
       int item1 , item2 , item3,item4;
               int nbUser;// test variable change later
         scanf(" %d", &nbuy);
    do{ // 
    switch (nBuy)
    {
        case 1 : 
                 scanf("%d",&item`enter code here`1);
                 item1 = nbUser;
        break;
        
        case 2 : 
                 scanf("%d",&item2);
                item2 = nbUser;
            
        break;
        
        case 3: 
                scanf("%d",&item3);
        break;
        
        case 4: 
                scanf("%d",&item4);
        break;      
                
        case 5: printf("Go back?\n");
                getStart( nbUser);  
        break;
        
        default : printf("You have entered invalid!");
        break;
    }
     printf("Press 5 to go back or Press 1-4 for buy\n");  //test code change later into better alternative
    scanf("%d", &nBuy);
```

and another function like this

Comment: Question not clear and so is the description, please edit and update

Comment: Just as a side note: It is unsafe to use `scanf` without checking the return value. See this page for further information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)